# openstreetmap get all places added through my account

Tags: php, openstreetmap

I have created an account on "openstreetmap" .

First how to add some location on OSM?

Second, I need to fetch all places or location added by me using my account on OSM using API.

Is there API available for doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't their documentation answer these questions?

Comment: @arkascha it shows many things related to open data search but i didnt got any point related to my location or atleast getting my "diaries" data.

Comment: Please be aware that OSM is an crowd GIS project that maps the reality. Don't use it to circumvent your own DB setup and just contribute data that are visible for everybody out there :-)

Answer (score 1):

Answering *how to add some location on OSM?*: Please see the [Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Beginners%27_Guide) from the OSM wiki and [Beginner's guide](http://learnosm.org/en/beginner/) from learnosm.org.

Answering *i need to fetch all places or location added by me*: There is no such API function. However you can [download all your changesets](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Query:_GET_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2Fchangesets) via the API and then examine each changeset for elements added by you.